# Calling a method from another class with an array of objects

Tags: java, object, methods

Im getting the null pointer exception error and i dont understand what is wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CDlist CD[] = new CDlist[5];
    CD[0].add();
}
```

That is my main, very simple, it just creates the 5 CD objects and calls the add method of the first object.

```
public boolean add(){
    String author;
    String title;
    String songTitle;
    int amount;
    boolean result = false;
    if(numUsed < length){
        System.out.println("Please input the name of the CD you wish to add.");
        title = input.next();
        CD[numUsed].title = title;
        System.out.println("Please input the author of the CD you wish to add.");
        author = input.next();
        CD[numUsed].title = title;
        System.out.println("Please input the amount of songs you want to have.");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++){
            System.out.println("Add song name:");
            songTitle = input.next();
            CD[numUsed].song[amount] = songTitle;
        }
        numUsed++;
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my add method in the CDlist class

Comment: Please post full error message with all the details. You `add` method uses variables that are neither defined nor assigned there, so please show us the relevant code where they are defined and/or assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The probem is

```
 CD[0].add();
```

`CD[0]` is null because of the way java arrays work:

```
CDlist CD[] = new CDlist[5];
```

This allocates an array new `CDList`s but the list is populated with `null` entries. In order for it to contain valid objects, you must populate in manually:

```
CDlist CD[] = new CDlist[5];
for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{
    CD[i] = new CDList(); //or other constructor, or other way of getting CD object
}
```

Without doing this, the array will contain nothing but `null` and attempting to call the method will fail because the object you are trying to call it on does not exist.

Comment: Im trying to create an array of objects, i currently have 2 classes that creates a CD object and adds a title/author and calls the tracklist class to add songs to it, i need to make another class that puts each CD object into an array.

Comment: Basically the point of what I'm saying is that you need to fill the array with objects yourself. If you have way of getting CD objects without directly calling the constructor, just replace `new CD()` with that code.

Comment: What im saying, is that when you create an array of ints, for example, you say  int[] array;   but how do i create an array of objects? do i have to create an object itself to do so? or am i going the wrong way with this.

Comment: the CDlist class is being made so that once i have the array of objects, i can add/delete and sort by author/title

Comment: Your syntax is correct. `CDList[] CD` declares an array of `CDList`s called `CD`. The only problem is that an array of `int`s is automatically filled with zeroes, which are valid values for `int`s. However, an array of objects is automatically filled with `null`s, which is not a valid value for an object.

Comment: So basically, instead of creating CD objects by such CD mycd = new CD();  I can add CDlist[] array; and create the CD objects by saying CD array[0] = new CD();  thus giving me an array called "array" with objects within it? Then i could call CDlist with the delete function and stuff, saying delete array[x];

Comment: Almost. Assigning a value to an element in an array does not require a declaration for that element: `array[0] = new CD();`, not `CD array[0] = new CD();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26125/discussion-between-user1801067-and-valekhalfheart)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to print out the CD array, you will see it looks like:

> null, null, null, null, null

You made an array of size 5, but unlike C++ it doesn't call the default constructor. You have to initialize them all.